# Grid Tile List in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I want to a make a tile box in angular JS such that I can display the Phone number and name coming from JSON.
The next tile should be used to add new phone numbers.As soon as we add something,It should be displayed next to each other.

Can any body help ?

Comment: Please add code reference that you tried

Comment: @pourushsingh What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MD Ashik: Yes,Ashik.I tried the code and then asked the question.I was not aware of posting the code so I asked about it.

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur so Please next time try to keep some code . It will be help you to get your answer fast and more batter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.existingConnections = [{
    "name": "Nancy",
    "PhoneNo": "111"
  }, {
    "name": "Philip",
    "PhoneNo": "222"
  }, {
    "name": "William",
    "PhoneNo": "333"
  }, {
    "name": "Matthew",
    "PhoneNo": "444"
  }];
  
  $scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.existingConnections.push({name:$scope.Name,PhoneNo:$scope.PhoneNo});
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div flex layout="row">
    <div layout="column" class="p10" flex="50">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" flex ng-model="Name" />
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout="column" class="p10" flex="50">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" flex ng-model="PhoneNo" />
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button type="button" class="p10" ng-click="submit()">
      Add
    </md-button>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-wrap flex>
    <md-card flex="30" ng-repeat="connection in existingConnections">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text layout="column" flex>
          <div layout="row" flex>
            <div><b> Name: </b></div>
            <div> {{connection.name}} </div>
          </div>
          <div layout="row" flex>
            <div><b> Phone: </b></div>
            <div> {{connection.PhoneNo}} </div>
          </div>

        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur you are welcome,upvote if it has helped

Comment: Hi ...Suppose I have keys like name,Phone and Type.Type must be in order like Mobile ,Home ,Work in a Chronological order.What should I do to follow this in this particular order only .

I have tried orderBy but can not achieve functionality as orderBy arranges in ascending order.